# how to kill or close specific connection on mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a two DB server.

```
-> Primary(27017)

-> Secondary(27022)
```

Now in my Project, at certain API want to create the request through secondary, After getting the request close the Secondary Connection because it is on demand Request. So every time server has to open when demands generate, serve the data and then kill/close that instances.

By default the command is:

```
mongoose.connection.close( function () {
    console.log('Secondary Server close Properly');
});
```

But this will kill the existing Primary Connection as well. Is there any approach by which I can kill Only Secondary server and primary keep alive

Comment: I don't use `mongoose`, however, a quick google says you can create multiple connections using `const conn = mongoose.createConnection(...)`. Then you can set the `readPreference` individually. Furthermore, you shouldn't have a Replicaset of 2. You should have at least 3, with an odd number of nodes (voters).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using something along the lines of

```
const primary = mongoose.createConnection(...)
const secondary = mongoose.createConnection(...)
// Perform the operations required

// When it comes to closing the connection
secondary.close()
```